# Get data from 2 tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with the same columns, i need to show them all from both tables, but now i get all columns in each row, ex. locator 2 times per row, it has to show only 1, from the correct table.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM  clothes a, items b group by a.locator,b.locator
```

How do i do this?

I will have it outputs from both tables with rows. "name","locator","price" and WHERE "ibutik" = 1.

Clothes table with test rows:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clothes` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `locator` varchar(48) DEFAULT NULL,
   `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
     `price` int(11) DEFAULT '100',
    `level` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
     `type` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `sex` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
     `x_offset` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
     `y_offset` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
     `nontradeable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
     `ibutik` int(1) NOT NULL,
     `koebt` int(9) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55 ;


 INSERT INTO `clothes` (`id`, `locator`, `name`, `price`, `level`, `type`, `sex`, `x_offset`, `y_offset`, `nontradeable`, `ibutik`, `koebt`) VALUES
   (1, '1.png', 'Male body', 100, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   (3, '1.png', 'Female body\r\n', 100, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

And items:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `locator` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT '100',
  `level` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `rotateable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `x_offset` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `y_offset` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `z_index` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `nontradeable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `ibutik` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;



INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `locator`, `name`, `price`, `level`, `rotateable`, `x_offset`, `y_offset`, `z_index`, `nontradeable`, `ibutik`) VALUES
(1, 'rodplante.png', 'Rød plante', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(2, '1.png', 'Gul plante', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(3, '2.png', 'Gul plante', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In can try something like:

```
select id,locator,name,price, tableName from 
(
  select a.id as id, a.locator as locator, a.name as name, 
     a.price as price, a.ibutik as ibutik, 'closes' as tableName 
    from  clothes a
  union all
  select b.id,b.locator,b.name,b.price,b.ibutik,'items' from items b 
) foo
where ibutik=0;
```

Validated with [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86650/8).

Comment: Thanks man! Great job. Is it possible to insert for each row, the table name in output, ex. "table" with is clothes or items, to "locate" where the output is from?

Comment: @user1743233 Sure, see my updated answer, note that I changed the where clause to `ibutik=0` to list more entries.